# Python: pickle: No code suggestion after extracting string object from pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

for example, this is my code:

```
#extract the object from "lastringa.pickle" and save it 
extracted = ""
with open("lastringa.pickle","rb") as f:
    extracted = pickle.load(f)
```

Where "lasting.pickle" contains a string object with some text.

So if I type `extracted.` before the opening of the file, I'm able to get the code suggestion as shown in the picture:

[image]

But then, after this operation `extracted = pickle.load(f)`, if I type `extracted.` I don't get code suggestion anymore.

[image]

Can somebody explain me why is that and how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, that is because in the first shot, the system knows than `extracted`is a sitring. In the second shot, the system doesn't know what kind of obejct you have in `extracted`because it knows that you are loading something from a file, but it is not executing it. It will know the type of data you are loading on execution time

Comment: so i guess i just need to parse the data loaded from the file.

Comment: Inside the 'with' statement: extracted = str(pickle.load(f)). Now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pickle reads and writes objects as **binary files**. You can confirm this by the `open('lastringa.pickle', 'rb')`, command where you are using the `rb` option, i.e. *read binary*.

Your IDE doesn't know the type of the object that the pickle is expected to read, so that it can suggest the string methods (e.g. `.split()`, `.read()`)

On the other hand, in the first photo, your IDE knows that `expected` is a string and it knows what to suggest.